# TideSDK createProcess starts wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby, process, version, tidesdk, createprocess

I am struggling with starting a new ruby process in TideSDK. I use the javascript:

```
my_process = Ti.Process.createProcess({
    args:['ruby',Ti.API.application.resourcesPath + "/ruby/some_process_scrpt.rb", get_argvs()]
});
my_process.launch();
```

Now this does start a new process, but it starts a ruby process in my systems environment, aka. it does not use the ruby that comes bundled with TideSDK. In my case, when querying and getting the ruby-version I get that it uses 2.0.0.

Is there a way to start a new ruby process in the ruby-environment that comes bundled with TideSDK?

(Ps. I have tried forking with little success.)

Comment: Does it work if you set the default system version using rvm?

Comment: Do you mean on the system itself, or in the project? The thing is that I am making a desktop app that ships with a version of ruby. It is not guaranteed that the target platform has Ruby installed.

I did however manage to get a fork to work. There was quite a bit of hustle with importing of gems and the like. I might post an answer here, even though it is not exactly the same thing.